# Displaying FQN in Expression.Call

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I am trying to get the string representation of a static method call that I created using expression trees. However, the textual representation does not contain the FQN of the method call. The code given below outputs **TestMethod()** instead of **AnotherClass.TestMethod()** which I need.

**Edit:** This is just a simple example. Ultimately the output can be something like this:-

```
AnotherClass.TestMethod<Guid>("BLOB_DATA", new MyClass())
```

So, I am not trying to just obtain the FQN of a method. The root expression object might not even be a method call. I thought that no matter how complex the expression is, doing a ToString() will return the C# code that can represent it.

The goal is to convert the root expression into C# code snippet that I can use and compile in memory.

```
using System;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ExpressionTest
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Variant 1
            MethodCallExpression call = Expression.Call(typeof (AnotherClass), "TestMethod", Type.EmptyTypes);
            Console.WriteLine(call.ToString());

            // Variant 2
            MethodInfo method = typeof (AnotherClass).GetMethod("TestMethod");
            MethodCallExpression call2 = Expression.Call(method);
            Console.WriteLine(call2.ToString());

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    internal class AnotherClass
    {
        public static void TestMethod()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string.Format("{0}.{1}", method.DeclaringType.Name, method.Name)
```

If (per recent edit to your Q) you want to turn the expression into something executable, you can instead do something like:

```
Action compiled = Expression.Lambda<Action>(call2).Compile();
```

You can then call the compiled expression as you would any other Action

Comment: I am not trying to just obtain the FQN of a method. The goal is to convert the root expression into C# code that I can use and compile in  memory. Sorry for not being clear, please see my edits to the question.

Comment: If you want to compile the expression in order to be able to call it, then you certainly don't want to go via a ToString() call on the expression. Expression.Lambda<T>() and Lambda<T>.Compile() are your friends here